# Does anyone have a good floating lable?

Tags: javascript, css, label, placeholder, floating-labels

A while ago I spotted [this](https://users.wix.com/signin?loginCompName=Signup_H&originUrl=https:%2F%2Fwww.wix.com&overrideLocale=en&postLogin=https:%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fmy-account%2Fsites&postSignUp=https:%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fnew%2Fintro&referralInfo=Signup_H&sendEmail=true&view=sign-up) floating label I have been looking for a similar working label since.

I have tried a couple that looked good and seemed to work just fine at first but they turned out to have their own problems like they either needed to have the required attribute otherwise they label would just look like a normal label or that the label goes back down when the input's type is an email.

so I was wondering if someone has a good substitute for this that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Material design has a nice floating label option. You can test it out here.
https://material.io/components/text-fields/

Answer (score -1):

I create a quick snippet for you. You can adjust it accordingly. Hopefully it helps.

With some transitions and the label positioned absolutely, we can achieve this effect.

If you have any questions, hit me up ;)

```css
.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.input-wrapper .input {
  padding: 8px;

  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  outline: 0;
  transition: all .15s ease-out;
}

.input-wrapper .input:hover {
  border-bottom-color: #444;
}

.input-wrapper .input:focus {
  border-bottom-color: #6200EE;
}

.input-wrapper .input:focus + .label,
.input-wrapper .input:valid + .label {
  top: -8px;
  left: 4px;
}

.input-wrapper .label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  top: 10px;

  padding: 0 4px;
  background-color: #fff;

  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;

  color: #444;

  transition: all .15s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input class="input" type="text" id="username" required>
  <label class="label" for="username">Label</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This one looks the way I want it to but it goes back down after you click away.

Comment: This was just a quick example, you could achieve the effect with for example JavaScript. I adjusted the snippet to get the effect you want, but with CSS only.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!  Turns out the problem I am having with the 
'input type email' is that when you enter a non-valid email (so just a string for example) the label goes down again, but it works when its a regular email. do you by any chance have a solution for this?

Comment: You could listen to the change event using javascript and check for a value. if the value length is bigger than 0, add a class to input-wrapper which handles the label position

Comment: Apparently this answer got downvoted, any body able to comment on the downvote?